# java.sql.Exception:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length exception

Tags: java, jdbc, 32bit-64bit

I did a project in java with Database as MS-Access.

While running the Application I got the following Exception in ***64 bit*** System but it is *working fine in 32 bit System*.

```
java.sql.Exception:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid string or buffer length exception.
```

1. I searched for root cause of Exception but I did not get clear clarification. I tried some other scenario's but I got the same Exception.
2. When I  try to insert the data more than 100 rows.
3. When I fetch the data even for  two columns also the Exceptions is throwing
4. When I fetch the data including `String` and `integer` the Exception is throwing but if I applied `getString()` for all datatypes it is working..
5. When I call jasper reports (I am passing the connection variable to jasper) at that time also the same Exception is throwing.

Can any one help me how to solve this Exception?

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some code here.

Comment: I would seriously consider using an alternative driver such as [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), as the JDBC-ODBC bridge is [no longer supported](https://blogs.oracle.com/Lance/entry/removal_of_the_jdbc_odbc)

Comment: Probably the connection driver used is for 32 bit System. Try to find the 64 bit driver.

Comment: Also check if the Java and the driver have the same architecture, 32 or 64.

Comment: I believe that the 64-bit version of the JDBC-ODBC bridge supplied with the Java runtime has problems, I've seen this exact error and IIRC it was using a 32-bit value instead of a 64-bit value for calling one of the ODBC functions. The only solution is to use a third-party bridge, especially considering the bridge is deprecated and is no longer being supplied as of Java 8.